# win 10 toast notification with an image in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to create an interactive toast notification in windows 10 using python?
Currently I am using `plyer` and sometimes I use `win10toast`.
When someone clicks it i want it to open a page in the web browser and contain an image, icon, text, and user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Image part, You can use the module [winrt](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/) like this:

```
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom

nManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
notifier = nManager.create_toast_notifier(r"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe")

tString = """
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>Another Message from Tim!</text>
            <text>Hi there!</text>
            <image placement="appLogoOverride" hint-crop="circle" src="https://picsum.photos/48?image=883"/>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
"""

xDoc = dom.XmlDocument()
xDoc.load_xml(tString)

notification = notifications.ToastNotification(xDoc)

#display notification
notifier.show(notification)
```

Also, There three places where you can put an image: [AppLogoOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml#app-logo-override), [Inline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml#inline-image) and [Hero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml#hero-image).

Answer (score 1):

I rummaged through the [source code](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/blob/master/win10toast/__init__.py) for win10toast and found they use [this library](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/) for creating windows gui elements and [here](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) is the most recent release. There you should be able to find the right module to use

Comment: It's better to mention some codes than just link  to somewhere else :(

Comment: The author did not present any code so why should I?