# How to add an image to desktop notification using plyer (PYTHON)

Tags: python

How can I add an image to this message iteself (not change the icon)?:

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify(
     title = 'testing',
     message = '',
     app_icon = None,
     app_name = 'Notifications',
     timeout = 10,
     )
```

Comment: Flagging this. Edit it so its an actual question.

Comment: kindly edit your question to make it more readable.  also refer to this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-desktop-notifier-using-plyer-module/

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. This site did not help me with adding an image to my message itself because it only shows that you can add an icon from the app.
Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Plyer does not offer to show images in the notification besides an icon.

See [How to create a system tray popup message with python? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows).

Also some alternatives do not offer this:

- [`pynotifier`](https://github.com/YuriyLisovskiy/pynotifier)
- [`win10toast`](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications), see: [win 10 toast notification with an image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826794/win-10-toast-notification-with-an-image-in-python)

Images, sound or interactive elements embedded to notifications depend heavily on your platform/OS:

- Windows, see [`winrt`](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/), also in [win 10 toast notification with an image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826794/win-10-toast-notification-with-an-image-in-python)
- Linux/Gnome, see [Desktop Notifications in Linux with Python | DevDungeon](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/desktop-notifications-linux-python)
- MacOS, see [`desktop-notifier`](https://github.com/samschott/desktop-notifier)
- cross-platform, see [`notify-py`](https://github.com/ms7m/notify-py)